# Android - Save 2 bitmap into just one Image file

Tags: android, android-image, android-bitmap, android-file

I want to save 2 bitmap into a **valid** image file side by side.

I can save all of bytes from booth bitmaps and the image file is a valid image byte and i can open and see that , but just first bitmap showed in the Image!

I tried this :

```
void save_bitmaps()
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/req_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    String fname = "Map"+ String.valueOf(10) + ".png";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        int count=0;
        //------------------------------------------
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500,500,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
        if(i==0)
            c.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
        if(i==1)
            c.drawColor(Color.RED);

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream);
        byte[] bytarray = stream.toByteArray();
        //----------------------------------------------------------------
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            out.write(bytarray,count,bytarray.length);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            count+=bytarray.length;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getContext() , "ERROR" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    Toast.makeText(getContext() ,"Saved" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

this code worked but not show both of them!

this is my aim :

[Target_Image_File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLPYM.png)

how i can do this . please help if you know how i can do this!

**NOTE :**
1. I never want to combine 2 bitmaps into another bitmap and save the target bitmap.

2. if you know another way to save 2 bitmaps into just one Image file without using byte array say it to me!

**Thanks all!**

Comment: `want to save 2 bitmap into a valid image file side by side`. You finally showed some code. But you forgot to tell what your code does now.

Comment: A valid png file can only hold one picture. So you request the impossible.  Gif and tiff can hold more. If you want that a png file is the result of two bitmaps then you have to combine those bjtmaps first to one bitmap.

Comment: The strange thing is that this is your third post for the same problem. In the first two you only wanted to write two bitmaps to the same file. That would be very easy. But it would not be a valid image file then. The `valid` is new for me. You could have mentioned that before.

Comment: `into a valid image file side by side.`. Not only valid but even side by side. If you would write them to one file they would be one after the other in that file. But you want them side by side? When? When the file is displayed? In the file already? How would you encode that? The only way is to combine the bitmaps first.

Comment: @greenapps tbQ bro . Yes i want too see the bitmaps side by side when image file is deisplayed .

Comment: @greenapps this code just create 2 bitmap and canvas just drawcolor into both of them . And then i compress them in png format then create byte array from the compressed stream ! Now i just write them to the image file . And this code save the bytes from both of bitmaps but just show one the first added bitmap ! More description ?

Comment: Your description what your code does is wrong. You create two bitmaps and compress them to file. But to files with the same name. Only the second file/bitmap will survive as the first one is overwritten.

Comment: @greenapps i never compress them to file i just compress them to stream not file ! ByteArrayOutputStream !

Comment: Irrelevant. Word picking. The thing is: only the second time the file survives.

Comment: @greenapps bro it work you can change the for lopp like this to just rune one time (int i=0;i<1;i++) and then check the saved file size . After this make the for loop for run more than one time and after the running u can check the size and u will see its work . And just shown the first bitmap added ! For sure about which bitmap show in the file u can use drawcolor . Diffrence colors for bitmaps can help !

Comment: Yes. Please try for yourself. Make the first yellow and the second blue and you will see that blue survives. Edit your post and add the code for it so we can see you tried in the right way.

Comment: @greenapps i tried this ! And the first color shown in Image file

Comment: Repeat: adapt your code so it does use different colors. We want to see what you did/do.

Comment: @greenapps i edit it and the file show the blue color!

Comment: Had a better look at your code now and discovered what happens. I will not tell you yet. But please do what you advised me to do. First generate a file where you loop only once. Then generate a file where you loop twice. You will see that the second time the file is twice as big. The second file will contain two images. But if you load it only the first one is displayed. So congratulations! You already managed to place two images in one file. Sadly its not a valid two image file.

Comment: @greenapps before ask any question i check it ! And it work like that i said . When the for loop is just once the file size is 4.7KB and  for any time the loop rune more than 1 time the size will (4.7×i)KB !

Comment: Do you mean  `and after the running u can check the size`. You could have told there what should be checked. That the size was twice as big. Would have saved me time.

Comment: @greenappa yes im sure its not a valid image for 2 image . But im sure there is way to do this .

Comment: @greenapps we talk about size then you must check it . Yes check the size . Can you make a better way to talk ? Whatsapp or something

Comment: You cannot only say 'check the content of the box'. You should also say what should be in the box. And i still did not try the code. So i cannot check file sizes. You should have told us the sizes. But you did not. Not informative. So all takes a lot of time.

Comment: @greenapps and after this comments ! Any way you think about it ?

Comment: Read my comments. All has been said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish, you can use this library I've made that can handle large image files via JNI :

https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AndroidJniBitmapOperations

But, it doesn't have this functionality that you wish. You will have to add it on your own:

1. create function/s for storing bitmaps from Java world to JNI world.
2. create a function for merging the images and getting the result.

You could even have just a single Java Bitmap object at the same time, instead of having 3 in the Java solution above (2 of input + 1 of output).

Some notes:

1. Using JNI can be slower, as it needs to convert from Java Bitmap object to JNI and back. This is especially true for large bitmaps.
2. In the end, you will still have to hold the output Java Bitmap object. If it's 10000x10000 pixels, it will take 10000*10000*4 bytes, which is 400,000,000 bytes, which is ~400MB . If the input images do not have transparency, you can use a different bitmap config ([**RGB_565**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html)) , which will take ~200MB of RAM.

   In both cases, this is a lot. You could add a flag in the manifest to tell the OS that you need a lot of heap memory ([**largeHeap**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap)) , but it isn't a safe way to get it, as you still might not get enough heap memory. You should check the amount of available heap memory before trying to create the output bitmap.
3. Another way to solve this, is to avoid showing the entire bitmap, because there is no screen on Android device that has this resolution. You could instead just show a part of the bitmap to be shown on screen, and the calculation stuff you could leave in JNI.
4. If my library isn't enough, there are other libraries that use JNI. I'm sure one of them can help.

Comment: TNX for this , i know u can help me for sure . but i need more help . can u let me to communicate with you in better way . like whats app or something else you think . its important for me . please if you can help me more answer me . tnX again

Comment: Its possible to add an bitmap into an Image file that exist before , without losing the bytes of current Image and show both of them side by side?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You wanted to merge 2 images into one. What do you mean "add bitmap" ? Add where? And how? What do you mean "without losing bytes"? It depends on how you compress it (JPEG will lose quality, but PNG and WEBP won't).

Comment: As i said i have abig view that i must create apictaure from this and i can create a bitmap with this size . I must create bitmaps from part of this and tehn save them . But the problem is i must add bitmaps one by 8one into the file ! I means i must save first bitmap to an image file and then save others bitmaps to the image file ! You understand what i means ? I never want to create another bitmap and combine them  inside of it and then save it !

Comment: You mean you want to add the image into the file, without decoding it? Without creating a new instance of a Bitmap object, at all? But where will you get the image data from? After all, image files are usually compressed in some way, so you have to decode them, and then you get the data in a Bitmap Object. If you'd deal with decompressed image files, you'd end up with huge files (about 400MB as I've written for the example above). If you do accept using JNI solution, you can do what you wish, adding one bitmap after another, but into a single image in RAM.

Comment: thkans , you mean i cant add one bitmap after another without using RAM , in my sd card or hard disk!?

Comment: It depends on what you wish to do. You could store the multiple bitmaps right into a file, without compressing, and managing the file on your own. Maybe create a "grid" of stitched images. It will avoid using RAM (except for the image you add, and later the huge image that you've created from all). But this will take quite a lot of space. Saving to PNG/JPEG/WEBP is the way to store it into relatively small sizes. In the end, having a 10,000*10,000 bitmap will be quite a lot to store in the heap. If it's still ok, it will all work using the JNI solution I've suggested

Comment: @AlirezaAkhoundi Look at the code of the library. It's open source. Do what you wish with it It has examples of multiple operations on bitmaps. It's mostly just a "game" on arrays...

Comment: @AlirezaAkhoundi I didn't say it is. I meant that what I do there is mess around with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

With the following code You can add images and save them Side by Side.
This worked for me.
All the best, hope you get your solution correct.

Im adding the save file function   inside combine image itself. You can change it as per your logic of how you need it implemented since the combined image will be the output of the function.

```
public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap c, Bitmap s) { 
Bitmap cs = null; 

int width, height = 0; 

if(c.getWidth() > s.getWidth()) { 
  width = c.getWidth() + s.getWidth(); 
  height = c.getHeight(); 
} else { 
  width = s.getWidth() + s.getWidth(); 
  height = c.getHeight(); 
} 

cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 

Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs); 

comboImage.drawBitmap(c, 0f, 0f, null); 
comboImage.drawBitmap(s, c.getWidth(), 0f, null); 

String tmpImg = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png"; 
String loc="IMAGE Combined-";
OutputStream os = null; 
try { 
  os = new FileOutputStream(loc + tmpImg); 
  cs.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os); 
} catch(IOException e) { 
  Log.e("combineImages", "problem combining images", e); 
}*/ 

return cs; 
}
```

Comment: How else do you wanna save the image if not a new one?

Comment: Please let me know your requirements of your final task with the combined image

Comment: please read my question correctly then answer . It cant help me !

Comment: L.S i want write 2 bitmaps into just one file and then show it . Why i want to do it ? Because the target image so big over (5000×5000) and i never cant create a bitmap for this size !

Comment: modify like dis      cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width/2, height/2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Comment: or  `cs.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 50, os); `

Comment: MY logic is mention a fixed size of the image which u want to create i.e,. heught and width

Comment: Athul L.S the hard space have not problem with big size file . But RAM is my issue. Thanks for help